# How do you post data to CouchDB both with and without using JavaScript

Tags: couchdb

I have a show which displays a form with fields populated from a document. I'd like to change the values in the field and then save the updated document.

I'm having trouble finding a clear, concise example of how to do this.

Seriously, just finishing this example would work wonders for so many people (I'm going to leave a lot of stuff out to make this concise).

**Install Couchapp**

This is outside the scope of my question, but here are the [instructions](http://couchapp.org/page/installing) for completeness.

**Create a couchapp**

Again, this is kind outside the scope of my question. Here is a perfectly concise [tutorial](http://benoitc.github.com/couchapp/getting_started.html) on how to create a couchapp.

**Create a template**

Create a folder in the root of your couchapp called *templates*. Within the *templates* folder create an HTML page called *myname.html*. Put the following in it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
            <fieldset>
                Hello <input type='text' name='name' value='{{ name }}'>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Create a show**

See the tutorial above for hwo to do this.

Add this code to a show called myname.

```
function(doc, req) { 
    if (doc) {  

        var ddoc = this
        var Mustache = require("vendor/couchapp/lib/mustache");

        var data = {
            title: "The Name",
            name: "Bobbert"
        }

        return Mustache.to_html(ddoc.templates.myname, data)
    } else {
        return ('nothing here baby')
    }
}
```

**Update the document with a new name by ...**

So who can complete this step via both the client side and the server side?

Please don't point me to the guide, I need to read it in your words.

Thanks.

*Edit:*

Although the return value isn't pretty, just posting a form to the update handler will update the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably want to look into [`update handler functions`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

An update handler handles granular document transformations. So you can take 1 form, that has one distinct purpose, and only update the relevant fields in your document via the update handler.

Your update handler will need to take a `PUT` request from your form. A browser can't do this directly, so you'll need some javascript to handle this for you. If you're using jQuery, this [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) can take your form and submit it seamlessly via AJAX using `PUT` for you.

Inside the function, you can take the fields you are accepting, in this case `name` and apply that directly to the document. (input validation can be handled via the [`validate_doc_update`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation) function)

### Update Handler (in your Design Document)

```
{
    "updates": {
        "name": function (doc, req) {
            doc.name = req.form.name;
            return [doc, "Name has been updated"];
        }
    }
}
```

### HTML

`<form id="myForm" action="/db/_design/ddoc/_update/name/doc_id">...</form>`

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        type: "PUT",
        success: function () { 
            alert("Thank you"); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Once you've gotten this basic example up and running, it's not much more difficult to add some more advanced features to your update handlers. :)

Comment: Thanks. One note about the code though. I noticed that using ajaxSubmit actually redirected my to the update handler, while using ajaxForm just displayed an alert without a redirect. [more info here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#tab6)