# How do I POST new data to CouchDB using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery) to the question below.
 I needed to setup a reverse proxy in apache which took about 2 minutes by adding the following line to my virual host; 
ProxyPass /couchdb/ http://dojo:5984/
Because of the same origin policy you can't post data across ports. I knew this applied to domains but not different ports so you set up a reverse proxy.

---

I would like to know how I can POST data to couchDB using JavaScript or jQuery.
I followed this [tut](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-couchdb/) and created a database and I'm able to post and get data using curl and it all works fine. There are curl examples below that I used. 
I'm also able to get data using jQuery but I don't know how to POST to CouchDB

curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/mycouchshop/_all_docs. 
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/mycouchshop/ -d @person.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"

I'm able to get and display data using jQuery. The code below works fine.

```
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://couchdb:5984/mycouchshop/_design/peoples/_view/people',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(json) {}
  });
```

But posting data results in a *405 Method Not Allowed*

```
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://couchdb:5984/mycouchshop/',
    data : {"forename": "Bob", "surname": "McHamster", "type": "person"},
    contentType : "application/json", 
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(resp) {}
  });
```

Comment: Try this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395338/how-do-you-post-data-to-couchdb-both-with-and-without-using-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395338/how-do-you-post-data-to-couchdb-both-with-and-without-using-javascript)

Comment: @cloudlight - I had a quick read of that post before. I will go back and have another read. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Same origins security policy

I am no couchapp expert, but I ran into the same issue. The problem is that your are getting into cross-domain restrictions, your app being served from one port and the couchdb being accessed on another port. From [couchapp.org](http://couchapp.org/page/what-is-couchapp):

> A common question I get from people starting to write Ajax apps using
>   CouchDB, is "when I try to query the CouchDB with jQuery, it doesn't
>   work." Usually it turns out that they have an index.html file on their
>   filesystem, which is attempting to do an Ajax call against the CouchDB
>   server. After I explain to them the same origin security policy, they
>   start to understand this this means CouchDB needs to serve their HTML
>   (rather than loading it in the browser direct from the filesystem).
>
> So, the simplest possible CouchApp is just an HTML file, served
>   directly from CouchDB, that uses Ajax to load and save data from the
>   CouchDB.

### Using couchapp

It seems that all application files need to be "pushed" to the couchdb server, using couchapp (http://couchapp.org/page/index). I am working from a Mac, so I used the [Standalone executable](https://github.com/downloads/couchapp/couchapp/couchapp-0.8.1-macosx.zip). Instructions to install couchapp are [there](http://couchapp.org/page/installing)

### A Tutorial

When you understand how couchapp works, you can use [this tutorial](http://blog.edparcell.com/using-jquery-and-couchdb-to-build-a-simple-we)

### Next steps

I am trying to figure them out... if you find anything good, please share! Good luck!

***EDIT:** I just found [this tutorial](http://custardbelly.com/blog/2010/12/08/jquery-mobile-couchdb-part-1-getting-started/)*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to resolve the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (**CORS**) issue is by changing some settings on your local CouchDB installation.

Just follow the answer posted on this Question: 
[Couchdb cors problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348630/couchdb-cors-problems)